# Supercomputer and undergraduates

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, genomics, computational-model

Is it common for an undergraduate to run their thesis (evolutionary genomics) in a supercomputer? In my country, few supercomputers exist, but I'm not sure how it is for bachelors in the US or Europe. I am writing my application to graduate school abroad and I want to know if it is a remarkable point I can use as hook to begin my statement.

Comment: This question would be better suited for academia SE.

Comment: If there are no pending jobs then you can use it. Why do you need supercomputer for. In any case this question is off-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about biology

Answer (score 2):

IMO irrespective of country and level (undergrad/Masters), if you can run a job on a High Performance Computing cluster or a supercomputer, you should mention that on your resume. And sure, you can use that in your statement, especially given the fact that not many have access to it, you had the rare opportunity and made full use of it.

In my experience, I haven't seen many undergrads here in the US that can run a job on a HPC - not without prior computing experience!

All the best to you!